# why this code returns Unsat?

Tags: z3, z3py

Given `c == a + 4` and `t == c + b`, if `b == -4`, then `t == a`. I am trying to do the opposite, meaning given the above 2 equations and `t == a`, I try to find value of `b`.

This is pretty similar to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293657/why-this-code-returns-unsat-formula-using-forall-implies), but this time I only switch `a` and `b`, and I am really confused that the code returns different result.

Following the code posted at above link, I have below code (similar, only `a` and `b` swiched):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from z3 import *

a, b, c, t = BitVecs('a b c t', 32)

g = True
g = And(g, c == (a + 4))
g = And(g, t == (c + b))

s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll([t, a, c], Implies(t == a, g)))
if s.check() == sat:
    print s.model()[b]
else:
    print 'Unsat'
```

However, on Ubuntu, running the above code returns unexpected result **Unsat**, but not value **-4** (or **0xfffffffc**)

Any idea why this is wrong?

Thanks so much.

Comment: `Round 2`??? Are we taking a quiz here?

Comment: no, what i wanted to say is this is related to another question. anyway, i fixed the title to make it less confused. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z3 is actually returning `unknown`. The method `check` returns: `sat`, `unsat` or `unknown`.
Here is a custom tactic that shows that the formula is indeed unsat.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
from z3 import *
a, b, c, t = BitVecs('a b c t', 32)

g = True
g = And(g, c == (a + 4))
g = And(g, t == (c + b))

s = Goal()
s.add(ForAll([t, a, c], Implies(t == a, g)))

T = Then("simplify", "der", "distribute-forall")
# print the simplified formula. Note that it is unsat
print T(s)

# Create a solver using the tactic above and qe

s = Then("simplify", "der", "distribute-forall", "qe", "smt").solver()
s.add(ForAll([t, a, c], Implies(t == a, g)))
print s.check()
```

**Update**
The formula is of the form

`forall t, a, c: t == a ==> c == (a + 4) and t == (c + b)`.

This formula is logically equivalent to:

`forall a, c: c == (a + 4) and a == (c + b)`.

which is logically equivalent to

`(forall a, c: c == (a + 4)) and (forall a, c: a == (c + b))`.

Both subformulas are logically equivalent to false.
This is why the formula is unsatisfiable.

The comment you wrote suggests that you believe you created the slightly different formula

`forall t, a, c: t == a ==> c == (a + 4) ==> t == (c + b)`.

This formula is `sat`. To create this formula we have to replace

```
g = True
g = And(g, c == (a + 4))
g = And(g, t == (c + b))
```

with

```
g = Implies(c == (a + 4), t == (c + b))
```

The updated example is available [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/Y3C1).

Comment: Oh, then Unknown is really unhelpful. Leo, do you recommend any solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: We can show that the formula is unsat by using a custom Z3 tactic/strategy. I updated the answer with the tactic.

Comment: Leo, this is really confused to me: if `b==-4`, then `t == c+b == (a+4)+-4 == a` with all value of `a`. Obviously `(t == a) => g` is satisfied with `b==4`, so why the above formula returns `Unsat`?? Thanks

Comment: Actually my original problem is that given `g` formula above (or something a bit more complicated), I want to find value of `b` so that `t==a` is true with all values of other variables (except `b`). This is why I proposed the formula `ForAll([t, a, c], Implies(t == a, g))`. Do you think this is a proper solution for my problem? Thanks a lot!.

Comment: I updated the answer with an explanation why the original formula is unsatisfiable.

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment.